# Unexpected token at the end of my script

Tags: jquery

I keep getting an unexpected token script error in developer tools. (fixed) Now I am getting an error involving my smarty function being used in my case..Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select[name=highSchool]").change(function () {
            switch ($("select[name=highSchool]").val()) {
                case 'Not yet attending':
                    $(this).parent().parent().sibling("tr#currentGrade").children("td#currentGrade").html(
                    "{html_options name='currentGrade' options=$currentGrade}");
                break;
                case 'Attending':
                    $(this).parent().parent().sibling("tr#currentGrade").children("td#currentGrade").html("");
                break;
                default:
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings("tr#currentGrade").children("td#currentGrade").html("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: PHP isn't going to process that Smarty function, because it's put on the page by the client.

Comment: It appears you are right. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second-to-last line should be: `});` otherwise your `.change()` is left unclosed.

Comment: That worked! Thank you :) If I add a smarty function "{html_options name='currentGrade' options=$currentGrade}"); It gives me another error saying expected identifier repeated 2 times.

Comment: @wowzuzz: It helps a lot to have a text-editor with good syntax highlighting. :)

Comment: Can you edit your original question to show where you're putting the Smarty function?

Comment: @wowzuzz: Not sure, but I did notice that you're using `tr#currentGrade` and `td#currentGrade`.. If you didn't know, you shouldn't repeat `IDs` on elements.